# Do all singular $n\times n$ matrices form a vector subspace when $n\ge2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove or disprove that the set of all $n\times n$ singular matrices form a vector subspace of $M_{nn}$ when $n\geq 2$. So, let:

$$
A_{n,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \cdots & a_{n,n}
 \end{pmatrix}
 ,\text{ where }a_{i,j}\in \mathbb R$$

I can't just take the case where $A_{n,n} = $ the zero vector and show the space is non-empty, closed under addition and scalar multiplication, can I?
this is only one case of $\det(A) =0$
so how can I prove/disprove this for all cases where $\det(A) =0$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**.  What do you get when you add
$$\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}\quad\hbox{and}\quad \pmatrix{0&0\cr0&1\cr}\ ?$$

Note that

- to prove a set is closed under addition you must show that if $M,N$ are in the set then $M+N$ is **always** in the set;
- to show a set is not closed under addition, you must find **one example** of $M,N$ in the set, such that $M+N$ is not in the set.

Comment: det(first) = det(second) =0 but det(first + second) = 1 ? 
Sorry but I'm still quite lost...

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Oh yes, how obvious!  I was so focused on trying to find a proof that I totally over looked this contradiction. Thank you David.